# Which statistics test to be used?

Tags: statistics

I want to run a statistics test in SPSS that tests the potential differences in two sets of data. The first set contains the following ten values:
13.7, 34.0, -68.0, 19.8, 20.9, 23.1, 22.5, 18.4, 30.3, 40.3

The second test contains the following 8 values: 
11.3, 11.8, 3.3, 34.1, 57.8, 19.2, 71.8, 18.8

I wonder which type of test that I should use? I want to evaluate whether there is a significant difference between the two sets of data. T-test, ANOVA?

I hope that my question is clear enough.

Thanks in advance!

Best regards, 
Daniel

Comment: Please respect the individual Stack Exchange sites. This is a Statistics question, hence it should be posted in Cross Validated site, not here. Statistics and Mathematics may have enormous intersection but they are distinct, at the end of the day.

Comment: @LandonCarter. Please respect other users' interpretations of what belongs on which site. This is not _just_ a question about SPSS, but involves some elementary issues in statistical theory. You will find many similar questions on the 'math' side; were they all improperly directed?

Comment: I found vighurt to be a new user and hence tried to show him the right direction. I am sorry if I turned out to be rude. Maybe I should have added a few smileys!! :) :)

Comment: Having said that, however, I often find several stats questions on this site, which should not happen. We do have a separate site that does not need any more logging in or pains, don't we? Let's keep this space clear!!

Comment: Statistics are no more distinct from maths than algebra is. Statistics is a branch of maths, just like geometry, algebra or calculus. So this is absolutely not off-topic.

Comment: It's not so much a question of which site could the question be appropriate for; it is more a question of which site (1) whose users can provide a more complete and specific answer; (2) might contain similar questions that have already been answered; (3) can best facilitate the learning goals of the person asking the question.

Comment: Without regard to what is or is not off-topic here, new userd should be made aware of the existence of Cross Validated where many stats questions get better treatment.  But this specific question might get closed there too!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to test whether there is a difference in population means, assuming these data come from two (nearly) normal populations, then you want a two-sample t test (do not assume variances equal).

I notice a negative number -68.0 in your first sample. Is that a typo, or what you really intended? If it's real, then some would say you should use a Wilcoxon rank sum test (on the grounds that one of the populations may not be normal).

I ran both tests in a different software package (with and without changing -68 to 68) and found no significant difference (at 5% level: either test, either way).

Note(s):$\,$ (1) I also checked for unequal population variances and found no
significance. However, your sample sizes are too small to detect considerable differences, even if real. (Tests for equal variances have very poor 'power' unless both samples are at least moderately large.)

(2) You asked about an ANOVA. You could view the question of equal population means as a one-factor ANOVA with two levels of the factor.
The P-value would be the same as for a two-sided, two-sample, pooled (assume equal variances) t test. But when there are only two levels of the factor, the t test is usually preferred.

Comment: If this is a useful answer, please click to accept, so it will eventually drop off the queue of questions without satisfactory answers. If you need something further, please be specific.